# Profile image from twitter in table view cells

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pull twitter profile image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115084/pull-twitter-profile-image)

Does anyone know how can i get profile image from twitter as well in table view cells? I'm using the following code to get username and text. But want to have profile image for a better clarity.

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [tweet objectForKey:@"from_user"],
                           [tweet objectForKey:@"text"]];
```

I'm borrowing the code from here if you need in any case.

- http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/06/16/searching-twitter-with-ios.html

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the image simply do:

```
cell.imageView.image = theTwitterImage;
```

otherwise, look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115084/pull-twitter-profile-image) @Legolas posted in the comments to your question. (I havent used the Twitter API before so I can't help you actually get the image.)